# Python Regex: Finding multiple occurrences with Findall() method, separated by |

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and currently learning **Regular Expressions.**

The code I made is:

```
import re
text = ('Batmobile lost a wheel. At least Batcopter is still okay.')
batRegex = re.compile(r'Bat(man|mobile|copter|bat')
mo = batRegex.findall(text)
print(mo)
```

When I run this, I get this:

```
['mobile', 'copter']
```

But I want to get something like:

```
['Batmobile', 'Batcopter']
```

Comment: Problem is with the capture group. Make it a **non-capture** group and check whether it has one or more occurrences. Like this: `Bat(?:man|mobile|copter|bat)+`

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't understand it fully but ```batRegex = re.compile(r'Bat(?:mobile|copter)')``` solved it!!

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 0):

So I re-coded according to the comment,
and changing

```
batRegex = re.compile(r'Bat(man|mobile|copter|bat')
```

to

```
batRegex = re.compile(r'Bat(?:man|mobile|copter|bat)')
```

yields the desired result of:

```
['Batmobile', 'Batcopter']
```

That solves the problem!